# Send email copy to client

Tags: php, function, email

I am wondering how to add a code to automatically send a copy as conformation to the sender. I need this code to send a exact copy to sender's email. I would appratite very much if someone can help.

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$emaill = $_POST['email'];

$to = "mail@mail.pt";

$boundary = "XYZ-".md5(date("dmYis"))."-ZYX";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=" . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "$boundary" . PHP_EOL;


if(mail($to, $assunto, $mens, $headers)){
```

I tried add

```
$headers .= "Cc: $emaill" . PHP_EOL;
```

But don't work.
Can you help me?